# AngularJS and Ruby on Rails Heroku Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, git, heroku

I have built an app using Ruby on Rails and AngularJS.  It is finished and working locally on my machine.  I am attempting to push it to heroku but I continue getting this error:

```
remote: -----> Fetching set buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku buildpack
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack https://github.com/
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-fa
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to aqueous-temple-93632.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/aqueous-temple-93632.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/aqueous-temple-93632.
```

I have looked at different tutorials and tried all their suggestions and nothing seems to work. My file structure is:

[image]

I created the app after logging in using `heroku create` and attempted tp push with `git push  <app name> master`

I have read that Heroku automatically finds the buildpack and so I am wondering if the fact I am using angularJS and RUby on Rails is what the issue is and if there is additional buildpacks I need to manually add.

Not sure if it is relevent but here is the gem file

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
gem 'sqlite3'
end




#Using postgres SQL as the db
group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem "activerecord-postgresql-adapter"
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported       runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

#Angular js gem
gem 'angularjs-rails'

#Angular js material designs gem
gem 'rails-angular-material'

gem 'angular-rails-templates'
gem 'bower-rails'

gem "heroku"

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
#gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Comment: I'm guessing that your app is nested inside an extra `angApp` directory. Your Rails app needs to be in the project root of your GIT repository for the heroku buildpack to work.

Comment: I am sorry, can you elaborate a little more on what you mean, I am new to all this.  I though I just needed to be where the .git file is in which is located in the main angRails directory

Comment: The `.git` directory needs to be in your Rails application root. That means it should be in same directory as `Gemfile` `\app` etc. not one directory above.

Comment: Hey you were right, I did not realize that and before you commented back I switched al lthe directories into the git root directory and still did not work.  I had to delete the .git file and start over with git and now it works.  Thank you very much

Comment: Yeah an alternative if you don't want to lose the project history would be to move all the rails files out of the nested `angRails` directory and then re-commit. If you are using RubyMine as it appears from the screenshot it uses `git mv` when you drag and drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Rails application needs to be in the project root of your GIT repository. That means it should be in same directory as Gemfile `\app` etc. not one directory above.

Anatomy of your typical rails project:

```
.            Gemfile      app          db           test
..           Gemfile.lock bin          lib          tmp
.git         README.rdoc  config       log          vendor
.gitignore   Rakefile     config.ru    public
```

If you are using RubyMine as it appears from the screenshot you can simply drag and drop the files in the IDE and then commit as it will use [`git mv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) under the hood.